# Invoke a non anonymous action or function to Task.Factory.StartNew() with more than one parameter

Tags: c#, action, anonymous, taskfactory

I want to use Task.Factory.StartNew() and invoke a named (non-anonymous) function into the StartNew(), Because I face an error that says

```
public static void Request<P, R>(RequestDelegateParamResult<P, R> del, P parameters, out R result, bool showError = true)
        {
            ...
            TaskFactory.StartNew(() => { del(parameters, out result) });
            ...
        }
```

[image]

What's your solution?

Thanks

Comment: There is an optional "state" parameter which is of type Object. Have you tried that? Link to official MS doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew?view=net-6.0#system-threading-tasks-taskfactory-startnew(system-action((system-object))-system-object-system-threading-cancellationtoken-system-threading-tasks-taskcreationoptions-system-threading-tasks-taskscheduler

Comment: Common solution is to use anonymous function: `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => printMessage(1, "2"))`

Comment: I've tried that, but what about for more than one params.

Comment: Can't you add the result to the RequestDelegateParamResult?

Comment: I am requesting a WSDL server that responds as 'result', thus I can not do your suggestion.